# Laravel Mix I have no access to my javascript class

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm, webpack, mixins

In my laravel project i have written an custom form validation class. after compiling with npm run dev i dont have access to this class.

**My files**

**small-form-validation.js**

```
class SmallFormValidator {
    errMsgs = {
        required: 'This field is required!',
        string: 'Not valid string.',
        ...
```

**my app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');
require('./myvendor/small-form-validator');
```

After compiling i found in the new created app.js file inside the public folder the source from class SmallFormValidator. It seems that he compiled right.

in my blade template i load with the mixing helper the app.js file.  in my Javscript inside the blade template  i cant create a instance of SmallFormValidation (*var sfv = new SmallFormValidation()* ).

I think the problems result that

1. I dont work with module export and so on
2. or i have some scope problems.

Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

an easy fix would be to assign it to your global/window object. in `small-form-validation.js` add `window.SmallFormValidator = SmallFormValidator` to make it globally accessible.

A better way would be to use module exports and imports

#### Example

```js
//add this add the end of the file
export default SmallFormValidator

// or to the line where you start declaring the class like so:
export default class SmallFormValidator {
  // class stuff
}
```

in the file where you want to use it you can import it like this:

```js
// top of your file
import SmallFormValidator from '../path/to/small-form-validation'

// use it how ever you want in this file
const smallFormValidator = new SmallFormValidator()
smallFormValidator.jeKaleZus() // or any other method you have
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Can you Explain the way with modules please?

Comment: It's a while ago but I updated my answer. May still be useful to select it as the accepted answer to help others out who have same question you had